# Jquerymobile Dialog with parameter

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can i get url parameter when open dialog ?

Sample Text

when dialog show, "`window.location.hash`" is "`#&ui-state=dialog`"
It don't have my parameter `name=abc`

how can i send my parameter to dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best advice is to fetch URL parameter by using server-side instead of client script.